# How do I find jars?

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee

I am using eclipse in Windows and a simple JSF example from the book Java EE7 Recipes.  I cannot find the following jars: "javax.enterprisse.context.RequestScoped" and "javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean".  I have searched for the files both in my pc and the net with no luck.  Is there a general way to find the correct .jar files?

Comment: What JDK version are you using?

Comment: You need to install a Java EE server, for example glassfish, install the adapter for Eclipse and then configure it accordingly in the settings. If you already have that, your server is probably lacking the JSF library or some paths are not right.

Comment: I am using jdk1.8.0_20 and EcipseIDE for Java EE developers.

Comment: I have spent all Sunday afternoon trying to find these jars with no luck.  They are,import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean; Am I setting up the project incorrectly?

Comment: Those are classes, not jars, and java.io.Serializable should be found in the JRE itself.

Comment: Ok, I have found Serializable, inject, and ManagedBean.  Serializable was in the jre as highlighed by nitind.  I found inject in another jar folder.  Got ManagedBean by setting Java Faces configuration in the Dynamic Web Project.  Still can't find "javax.eterprise.context.RequestScoped".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for providing input.  I found a download for javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped.  I found that when you type "javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped download" in google it brings you to a download site.  That's all that was needed.

Answer (score 1):

There are loads of sites available on web to find jars for a given class. Some popular sites are [Help4J](http://help4j.com/), [GrepCode](http://grepcode.com/), findJar etc. It comes handy for developers.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to install Netbeans with JavaEE Bundle for rapidly develop Java EE Apps because the whole infrastructure is provided. https://netbeans.org/downloads/